# EAS Update isn't initializing on iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, eas

I have to update my project (bare workflow) from Expo SDK 45 to 49 and I also had to migrate from `expo publish` to the new eas update.

I follow this guide to integrate it basically from scratch https://docs.expo.dev/eas-update/updating-your-app/

I'm configured the app.config.json with the following info

```js
//removing unnecesary information
//.....
runtimeVersion: "1.0.0",
updates: {
  url: "https://u.expo.dev/e6caa90c-fb71-4616-bcb0-XXXXXXX"
}
```

this is generating the following expo.plist file when I deploy using eas build

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>EXUpdatesCheckOnLaunch</key>
    <string>ALWAYS</string>
    <key>EXUpdatesEnabled</key>
    <true/>
    <key>EXUpdatesLaunchWaitMs</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <key>EXUpdatesURL</key>
    <string>https://u.expo.dev/e6caa90c-fb71-4616-bcb0-XXXXXXX</string>
    <key>EXUpdatesRuntimeVersion</key>
    <string>1.0.0</string>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

My eas.json (develop profile) looks like this

```json
   "develop": {
      "distribution": "store",
      "env": {
        "ENVIRONMENT": "develop",
        "EAS_BUILD_REF": "true"
      },
      "channel": "develop",
      "ios": {
        "buildConfiguration": "Release",
        "scheme": "myScheme"
      },
      "android": {
        "gradleCommand": ":app:bundleDevelopmentRelease"
      }
    },
```

The problem is that the updates that I'm sending to the branch `dev` (which is linked to develop channel) never come to the app, so I try to fetch them manually with the following method

```js
  const onCheckUpdate = async () => {
    try {
      const update = await Updates.checkForUpdateAsync();

      if (update.isAvailable) {
        await Updates.fetchUpdateAsync();
        await Updates.reloadAsync();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      alert(`Error fetching latest Expo update: ${error}`);
    }
  };
```

Here, I noted that the app is allways failing when it try to get updates, it generates the following exception

> Can't complete the operation (EXUpdates.UpdatesNotInitializedException 1)

I was looking on github issues and on stackoverflow, or eas documentation and i can't find why this is happening

someone has had this problem before?

thanks!

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Did you ever solve it?